# Magento Shipping charge

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am new to Magento . I am trying to add the shipping charges to my products under " weight vs destination " , I created the tablerates.csv file , my csv looks something like below.

```
Country,Region/State,"Zip/Postal Code","Weight (and above)","Shipping Price"
```

IN,Karnataka,*,0,40

IN,Karnataka,*,500,70

IN,Karnataka,*,1000,100

IN,Karnataka,*,1500,130

Shipping charges get added properly if price is less than 500rupees , if it exceed more than 500rs , that shipping charges changes to 0. I have disabled the free-shipping also , so there is no question of free shipping is getting enabled and shipping charges is becoming 0 . I am still not able to figure out why my pricing is creating problem in spite of me using weight vs destination .

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem , problem was in promotion , in promotion there was a condition where if product rate is more than 500, its free shipping . I deleted that clause . Now it works fine.